# What method or tool is available to make the following type of hole/indent in a piece of wood?

Tags: tool-selection, router-bit, holes

I would like to make a sphere like hole in a piece of wood like the image below. Is there a special bit or tool to do this?

[image]

Comment: There's some overlap with [this previous Question](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/2349/making-a-small-indent-crevice-depression-for-a-ball/).

Comment: Also closely related to [this](http://woodworking.stackexchange.com/questions/1168/can-i-use-a-plungable-router-bit-on-a-drill-press/1171#1171)

Comment: @Graphus When I read this I thought it would be a dupe of the question you linked. Do you think that it is not a duplicate?

Comment: @Matt, I don't think it's an exact duplicate no.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for a *[round nose bit](http://www.rockler.com/freud-round-nose-router-bits-1-4-in-shank)*, like the one pictured below.

[image: round nose]

It also looks like the edges of the hole are rounded over, for which you'd also use a *[roundover bit](http://www.rockler.com/roundover-beading-router-bits-1-2-inch-shank)*.

[image: roundover]

You could also take care of rounding the edges with sandpaper or a file/rasp.

Comment: The roundover bit won't work in this case due to the bearing and the concave hole. But a template and a collar to the router would.

Comment: The roundover will work for the most part, as long as it's set up correctly. It will require a little fairing with sandpaper afterward.

Comment: And a plunge router